# Target all direct children of a div except images

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to target all **direct children** of a div except images? Using the `:not`-selector or something similar?

Example: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hlrAg

Using a media query, all elements inside a div.wrapper should get a left/right-padding, except for the images. They should be the full width of the viewport.

I have tried:

```
.wrap > :not(img) {padding: 0 10px;} // (not working - EDIT: works!)

.wrap * :not(img) {padding: 0 10px;} // Creates a double padding on child->child elements.
```

Comment: The first one should work.

Comment: instead of setting `padding:0 10px`, just try `display:none` and you'll see in fact it works here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xkctm. Also I cannot imagine how `padding: 0 10px` affects an `img`? Note that `img` ***is not a container***.

Comment: This appears to be a browser-specific problem. The selector you've marked as "(not working)" works fine in Chrome ([CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CybJu)). Which browser are you using? **Edit:** This comment relates to the first revision of this question.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: You're right! The first example do work. I just had a typo in my classname... I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.wrap > *:not(img) {padding: 0 10px;}` (Which functions the same as `.wrap > :not(img)`.)

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vtrpF

---

However, if IE8- or other older browsers that don't support `:not` are a concern, use the following:

```
.wrap > * {padding: 0 10px;}
.wrap > img {padding: 0;}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/atfEc

Comment: You got it right but could you explain why OP's code didn't work

Comment: "You just need to combine the `*` and `>` selectors." No, you don't need the `*` - it's implied.